# How to retrieve records of bidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have list of products that need to be kept in different shopping carts.

I need to know which products have reached to any of the shopping carts,(in other words, which products are in a shopping cart) my classes are as following but the code runs into following error.

I designed the classes in this way to be able to retrieve all the carts that have products.
Each product can be in ONLY ONE cart, as quantity of all products is always one.

**Cart class**

```
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Cart{

  ...
  @OneToMany
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList();
  ...
}
```

**Product**

```
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Product{
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private Cart cart;
  ...
}
```

**Code 1**

```
 Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Product.class, "pro");
                cre.add(Restrictions.eq("pro.status", true))
                List<Product> pro = (Product) cre.list();

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cart_id' in 'field list'
```

**Code 2 (This a seperate code that does not work as well and throws a similar error)**

```
 Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Cart.class, "cart")
                        .createAlias("cart.products", "pro");
                cre.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("pro")); //has product
                List product = new ArrayList();
                product = (List<Product>) cre.list();

SEVERE:   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
....

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'pro1_.cart_id' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor598.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
```

Comment: I guess there  should be column conflicts .Like wise try to use like Unknown column 'pro1_.cart_id' as pro1.cart.id .We supposed to Entity Names as Table name in the HQL .

Comment: @Gk. so whats your solution? should I change the column names ?

Comment: Yes you should use the column name as in the Entity where ever use it .

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. It should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")`. And you didn't show how your tables looked like. Is there a cart_id column in the product table? How do you make the link between a product and its cart at the database level?

Comment: actually in this case each product can only be in one shopping cart, thats why the products member of cart is not a collection